# How to add a not null constraint in an existing column in DB2 iSeries?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, iseries-navigator

I have tried the following scripts to add a not null constraint to my column.

```
ALTER TABLE MYDB.RULES ALTER TYPEID SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE MYDB.RULES ALTER COLUMN TYPEID SET NOT NULL;
```

I also get this error when I execute it:

```
 Reason code 10. [SQL State=57014, DB Errorcode=-952]
```

Is it possible to do this in DB2 iSeries?

Answer (score 4):

First you have to identify and handle the NULL values of the target table ( update, delete, etc. )

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MYDB.RULES WHERE TYPEID IS NULL;
```

Than you can create the constraint on the target table.

```
ALTER TABLE MYDB.RULES ALTER COLUMN TYPEID SET NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE MYDB.RULES ALTER TYPEID SET NOT NULL;
```

Is correct.

How are you issuing the statement?

The error code you report, SQL State= `57014 - Processing was canceled as requested.`

Leads me to believe that however you're running the statement, you're not seeing the `CPA32B2 - Change of file RULES may cause data to be lost. (C I)` inquiry message; thus it's getting automatically answered with a `C-Cancel`.

Comment: Any solution to force an "I" answer using SQL ? This is a real pain in the foot with DB2/iSeries...

Comment: Google `CPA32B2`, you can Add Reply List Entry (`ADDRPYLE`) and  Change Job (`CHGJOB`) to use the system reply list.

Answer (score 0):

try this, with type of column

```
ALTER TABLE yourlib/yourtable ALTER COLUMN yourcolumn SET DATA 
TYPE VARCHAR ( 100) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constraint you add a constraint.  First you make sure all the rows in the table satisfy the constraint then add the constraint.

```
update mylib/myfile set myfield = ' ' where myfield is null;
ALTER TABLE mylib/myfile ADD CONSTRAINT myfieldisnull CHECK (myfield is not null );
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you altered the table before and didn't run the Reorg command. Run this:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE MYDB.RULES');
```